# Where is the FullText search Feature on SQL Server Express 2008 r2?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, full-text-search

According to this page (from July 2010), SQL Server express included the fulltext feature:

http://dotnetguts.blogspot.com/2010/07/download-sql-server-2008-r2-express.html

Today (March 4th) I tried to download does not include it. I Downloaded the 64 bit version with tools and it is not included. Did Microsoft change this? Is there a way to get FullText now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to download SQL Server 2008 R2 Express SP1 with Advanced Services. Full-Text Search does not come with the smaller, basic, Express edition.

You want to download the following file [from this location](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=26729):

> SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU.exe - if you use a 64-bit operating system
>   SQLEXPRADV_x86_ENU.exe - if you use a 32-bit operating system